# ffmpeg mp4 video created from mp3 with image has longer duration

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to convert an mp3 to mp4 with images. Below are two `ffmpeg` commands I tried.

Length of mp3: 23 sec

1. Here, the length of the video is same as the mp3, but video's sound does not work when trying to play on an iPhone:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i vidimage.jpg -i my.mp3 -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p my-video.mp4
```

2. Here, the mp4 plays with audio on an iPhone, but it is only 25 seconds long:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i vidimage.jpg -i my.mp3 -shortest -acodec aac my-video.mp4
```

Between the two commands, how can I get an MP4 with the same length as the source audio *and* plays properly on an iPhone?

Comment: Add `-fflags +shortest` for a closer result.

Comment: Unable to find a suitable output format for '+shortest'
+shortest: Invalid argument

Comment: Share full command and log.